# Why data can't be retrieved from another class on MapsActivity

Tags: android, json

Here I tried to store values in a class that I got from JSON, but later I can't retrieve those data from that class.

> int length= rnty.renter_id.size(); returning 0 when I initialized that class again. but on debugging mode it shows that data is being stored correctly.

try {

```
   JSONObject json_object= new JSONObject(json_string);
        JSONArray json_array= json_object.getJSONArray("response");
        int count = 0;
        String renter_id,address,lat,longitu,rate;
       renterMarkerInformation rntr= new renterMarkerInformation();
        while(count<json_array.length()){
            JSONObject jo= json_array.getJSONObject(count);
            renter_id= jo.getString("renter_id");
            address= jo.getString("address");
            lat= jo.getString("latitude");
            longitu= jo.getString("longitute");
            rate=jo.getString("rateperhour");
            rntr.setRenter_id(renter_id);
            rntr.setAddress(address);
            rntr.setLattitude(Double.parseDouble(lat));
            rntr.setLongitude(Double.parseDouble(longitu));
            rntr.setRate(Integer.parseInt(rate));
            //LatLng sydney = new LatLng(Double.parseDouble(lat), Double.parseDouble(longitu));
            //mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(sydney).title("Marker in Sydney"));

            count++;
        }
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    renterMarkerInformation rnty= new renterMarkerInformation();
    int length= rnty.renter_id.size();

    for(int i=0;i<length;i++){
        LatLng sydney = new LatLng(rnty.getLattitude(i), rnty.getLongitude(i));
       mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(sydney).title(rnty.getAddress(i)));
      // mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(sydney,19.4f));
    }
```

**

> Here is another which I'm accessing.

**

public class renterMarkerInformation {

```
ArrayList<String> renter_id= new ArrayList();
ArrayList<String> address= new ArrayList();
ArrayList<Double> lattitude= new ArrayList<>();
ArrayList<Double> longitude= new ArrayList<>();
ArrayList<Integer> rate= new ArrayList<>();

public void setRenter_id(String renter_id) {
    this.renter_id.add(renter_id);
}
public void setAddress(String address){
    this.address.add(address);
}
public void setLattitude(Double lattitude){
    this.lattitude.add(lattitude);
}
public void setLongitude(Double longitude){
    this.longitude.add(longitude);
}
public void setRate(Integer rate){
    this.rate.add(rate);
}

public String getRenter_id(int index){
    return renter_id.get(index);
}
public String getAddress(int index){
    return address.get(index);
}
public Double getLattitude(int index){
    return lattitude.get(index);
}
public Double getLongitude(int index){
    return longitude.get(index);
}
public Integer getRate(int index){
    return rate.get(index);
}
```

}

Comment: because scope of your variable is over. Declare it as a class level variable.

Comment: If you want to use that variable value in another class then make use of Shared Preferences.

Comment: Thanks. I missed that accidentally. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Scope of your variable is over as soon as your try completes as your variable is defined in try block and has block scope only. Try declaring your object at class level and use it.

```
class XYZ{

    renterMarkerInformation rntr;
    ...

    try {
        rntr =new renterMarkerInformation();
    }
    ...

    LatLng sydney = new LatLng(rntr.getLattitude(i), rntr.getLongitude(i));
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your help.